# Проблема в последнем else. Нужно что бы не выдавало ошибку, изначально делал "Prov" типом "char", как выяснилось, нужно что бы он был типом "int"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, ввод

Программа должна получить цифры в текстовый файл, и вывести те числа, которые являются числами Фибоначчи. Перед последним, как раз проблемным ифом, стоят два цикла. Может показаться что они лишние, но один отвечает за перечень самих чисел из файла, второй же, отвечает за сравнение с каждым числом фибоначчи, (в данном случаи до тридцатого) Опять же, проблема в условии цикла "while(fin.get(Prov))", когда Prov был типа char ошибок не было, но работал не правильно, символ цифры не может ровняться цифре, по логике VS. Сейчас тип  Prov, заменен на int.
!!!!!!!! Вот эта формула описанная в комментарии.

```
#include <iostream>
```

using namespace std;

int Fib(int i)

{

int value = 0;

if(i < 1) return 0;

if(i == 1) return 1;

return Fib(i-1) + Fib(i - 2);

}

int main()

{

int i = 0;

while(i < 47)

{

cout << Fib(i) << endl;

i++;

}

return 0;

}

```
Затем идёт код... (уже не так важен код как эта формула)
Проблема в том, что бы эту Функцию воплотить в цикле, что бы было возможно проверить каждое число в файле. Мало кому это понадобится, хотя как видно мне пригодилось бы.





#include "pch.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "fstream"
#include "locale.h"
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    setlocale(0, "");
    string chis = "MyProgFile.txt";
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(chis, ofstream::app);
    if (!fout.is_open())
    {
        cout << "ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR";
    }
    else
    {
        int i,j, chislo,Rozmer;
    cout << "Укажите количество чисел - ";
    cin >> Rozmer;
    cout << "Заполните текстовый файл"<<endl;
    for (i = 0;i < Rozmer;i++)
    {
        cin >> chislo;
        fout << chislo<<endl;
    }
    }
ifstream fin;
fin.open(chis);
int x0 = 0, x1 = 1,j=0;
if(!fin.is_open())
{
    cout << "ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR";
}
else
{
    cout << "Файл открыт"<<endl;
    int Prov;
    int MF[] = { 0,1 };
        while(fin.get(Prov))
        {
            while (j>30)
            {
                if (Prov == (MF[x0] + MF[x1]))
                {

                    x0++;
                    x1++;
                    cout << Prov;
                }
                else
                    cout << "ERROR ERROR ERROR";
            }
        }
}
fin.close();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: "символ цифры не может ровняться цифре, по логике VS"... А вы где-то видели С++ компилятор с другой логикой? Расскажите, пжлст.

Comment: Также, зачем вы вообще прицепились к функции `ifstream::get`. Нет, эта функция не может прочитать `int` так, как вы пытаетесь это сделать - она для этого не предназначена. Но как эта `get` вообще появилась в вашей программе? С чего это вдруг вы начали использовать эту редкую узкоспециализированную функцию?

Comment: @AnT Где конструктив . Если бы я был таким умным, и знал бы что здесь фун-я ifstream::get неактуальна, я бы не задал этот вопрос. Во вторых, вопрос уже не актуален как и комментарии выше. Что ты тут делаешь, пытаешься помочь, или что, толку ноль.

Comment: Вы, видимо, что-то не понимаете. Вопросы, которые я задал выше - они не риторические. И ответы на них - это и есть шаг к "конструктиву". Но вы, как мне кажется, хотите не "конструктива", а того, чтобы за вас все сделали. Тогда мои вопросы действительно неуместны. Бывает...

Comment: @AnT Если бы я хотел что бы за меня всё сделали я бы не написал эту относительно не маленькую программу. По поводу конструктива, мне не нужны ребусы, если есть ответы на вопросы, можете их предоставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы намереваетесь получать число именно из одной цифры - то таки пусть `Prov` будет `char`, а после чтения - добавьте

```
Prov -= '0';
```

Но если это должно быть многозначное число, то лучше работать как

```
int Prov;
while (fin >> Prov)...
```

Comment: Спасибо Harry, Всё начало работать, но вылезло с другой стороны, как выяснилось у меня не верная формула выявления числа Фибоначчи. Я нашёл что то подобное, работает правильно, но думаю это другой язык, как это всунуть в С++ не знаю, если есть идеи буду рад.